# AWS Lambda function to resize instance by tag

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that resizes EC2 instances but the instance id is hard-coded - I would prefer to use tags but can't get it to work

Here's the code that works:

```
# lambda function
import boto3
import botocore
import os

# define environment variables
Instance_Type = os.environ['InstanceType']

#define the connections
client = boto3.client('ec2')

RunningInstances = 'i-02a1130833c928708'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Stop the instance
    client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[RunningInstances])
    waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[RunningInstances])
    print "Stopped", RunningInstances

    # Change the instance type
    client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=RunningInstances, 
    Attribute='instanceType', Value=Instance_Type)
    print RunningInstances, "resized down to", Instance_Type

    # Start the instance
    client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[RunningInstances])
    print "Started", RunningInstances
```

Here's what I'd like to work:

```
import boto3
import botocore
import os

# define environment variables
Instance_Type = os.environ['InstanceType']

#define the connections
client = boto3.client('ec2')

#RunningInstances = 'i-02a1130833c928708'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters=[
            {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['ResizeDown']},
            {'Name': 'tag-value', 'Values': ['True']},
            {'Name': 'instance-state-name','Values': ['running']}
    ]

    #filter the instances
    instances = client.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    #locate all running instances
    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    # Stop the instance
    client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[RunningInstances])
    waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[RunningInstances])
    print "Stopped", RunningInstances

    # Change the instance type
    client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=RunningInstances, 
    Attribute='instanceType', Value=Instance_Type)
    print RunningInstances, "resized down to", Instance_Type

    # Start the instance
    client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[RunningInstances])
    print "Started", RunningInstances
```

the error I get is:

> 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances': AttributeError
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21, in lambda_handler
>           instances = client.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
>         File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 555, in **getattr**
>           self.**class**.**name**, item)
>       AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error says, your `EC2` object has no attribute `instances`, and if you look in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#client) you won't find it there. You should just be able to use the [`describe_instances`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) function on your boto client with the filter you already set up, and that will return you the relevant instances as before, ie:

```
instances = client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it fixes the error, but the code does not work after. As John points out I'm using two different ways to reference aws. I'm not a python programmer, so I'll stick with the code that works.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```py
instances = client.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
```

is using the format for an EC2 **resource** rather than an EC2 **client**.

You could use:

```py
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2_resource.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
```

Basically, it's two different ways of referencing AWS. The `client` approach maps to the AWS API, while the `resource` approach is more Pythonic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, works but code after doesn't.  I've selected danimal's answer as the solution, as it fixes the error message and was first, the rest of the code throws so many errors I'm sticking with the code that works.